# Regex extract parts of file names in R

Tags: r, regex

I am reading in multiple excel files into R and I want to use parts of the filenames as data.
My file names are in list and look like this:
"Folder//study30/01_study30_Baseline.xlsx" and "Folder//study30/01_study30_6M.xlsx"

I extract the study number (in this example, `30`) like this:

```
qtest = "Folder//Subfolder/study30/01_study30_Baseline.xlsx"
qt1 = gsub("Folder//Subfolder/study", "", qtest) 
qt1
[1] "30/01_study30_Baseline.xlsx"

qt2 = gsub("\\/\\S+\\.xlsx$", "", qt1)
qt2
[1] "30"
```

Now I want to extract the time, in these examples "Baseline" and "6M".
This is my attempt, reading backwards from ".xlsx":

```
time = grep("/\\_[A-Za-z0-9]+\\.xlsx$", t1 , value= T)
```

This is incorrect. What is the correct regex to get "Baseline" and "6M" in  these examples?

Comment: I like this clear readable one: `gsub(".*_|\\.xlsx", "", x)`

Comment: also try `tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(gsub("_", "/", qtest)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.*` is greedy so it will match everything up until the last `_`. Then you can capture `()` one or more `+` word characters `\\w` before `.xlsx`:

```r
sub(".*_(\\w+)\\.xlsx$", "\\1", x)
```

You don't necessarily need a regular expression to do this (though technically `sub` is using a regular expression):

```r
x <- c("Folder//study30/01_study30_Baseline.xlsx", "Folder//study30/01_study30_6M.xlsx")

sapply(str_split(sub(".xlsx", "", x), "_"), tail, 1)
# [1] "Baseline" "6M"
```

Remove the extension using `sub`, split the remaining file name by "_", and take the last split using `tail`.

Alternatively, you can just split the paths by "_" or "." and select the third element:

```r
sapply(str_split(x, "_|\\."), `[`, 3)
```

Comment: i really like the use of str_split here. What does the `[` reman in your final option?

Comment: @MarkDavies `[` is used in R to extract an element. You may be more used to seeing it like this: `x <- 1:3; x[3]` to extract the third element. However, you can use it like a function: `\`[\`(x, 3)`. In using it as a function we can then apply it over the result of `str_split` to extract the third vector element of each list item.

Comment: This could be rewritten more verbosely as: `sapply(str_split(x, "_|\\."), \(y) y[3])`

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```r
sub("^(?:.*_)?([^_/]+)\\.xlsx$", "\\1", qtest)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oaked6/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:.*_)?` - an optional sequence of any zero or more chars as many as possible until a rightmost `_`
- `([^_/]+)` - Group 1 (`\1` refers to this text in the replacement pattern): one or more chars other than `_` and `/`
- `\.xlsx` - a literal `.xlsx` text
- `$` - end of string.

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/LL8iVA):

```r
x <- c("Folder//Subfolder/study30/01_study30_Baseline.xlsx", "Folder//study30/01_study30_6M.xlsx")
sub("^(?:.*_)?([^_/]+)\\.xlsx$", "\\1", x)
## => [1] "Baseline" "6M"
```